# Can you run the same loop simultaneously 3 times in a single bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell, asynchronous

If you could just point me in the right direction I'm sure I could figure it out eventually.

I have a loop that works from i=1 to i=75.  But I am able to run this a maximum of 3 times concurrently so all I could figure out is running it in 3 separate terminals as i=1 to i=25, i=26 to i=50, and i=51 to i=75.

Ideally I would want it run in the same script and for all 3 instances of the loop simultaneously and to begin at i=1 and end at i=75, however without overlapping i's which have been completed or are being completed by a different instance of the loop.

Example processing:

- Loop1 begins i=1
- Loop2 skips i=1, Loop2 begins i=2
- Loop3 skips i=1,2, Loop3 begins i=3
- Loop2 completes i=2, Loop2 skips i=3, Loop2 begins i=4
- Loop3 completes i=3, Loop3 skips i=4, Loop3 begins i=5
- Loop1 completes i=1, Loop1 skips i=2,3,4,5 Loop1 begins i=6
- Loop1 completes i=6, Loop1 begins i=7
- Loop3 completes i=5, Loop3 skips i=7, Loop3 begins i=8

the structure of the loop is basically like this

```
u=0
while [ $u -lt 1000 ]
do
    ((u++))
    i=$1
    while [ $i -le $2 ]
    do
        curl #(that sends begining command $i)
        sleep 60
        variable1=$(curl $i) #command that outputs a number which can change every 60 seconds
        variable2=$(curl $i) #command that outputs a number which is static
        counter=0 
        until [ variable1 -ne $variable2 ]
        do
            ((counter++))
            echo waiting 60 seconds 
            echo times waited: $counter
            sleep 60
            variable1=$(curl $i) #command that outputs a number which can change every 60 seconds
            variable2=$(curl $i) #command that outputs a number which is static
        curl #(that sends ending command $i)
        ((i++))
        done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide a simple way to accomplish this, and I let you to customize it per your needs:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function myLoopFunction {
  param1 = $1
  param2 = $2

  # Some code...
}

myLoopFunction value1a value2a & # Run 1
myLoopFunction value1b value2b & # Run 2
myLoopFunction value1c value2c & # Run 3

wait # Wait for termination...
```

Comment: are they able to pass variables through each other like that? so if the Run 2 function changes a variable x from 2 to 3 will Run 1 be able to see that x is now 3 not 2?

Comment: Sure, I edit it for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
N=3
for (( i = 0; i < N; i++ ))
do ( 
    switch $i in
       0) setup_loop_0 ;;
       1) setup_loop_1 ;;
       2) setup_loop_2 ;;
    esac

    echo any commands
    sleep 2
    echo finish
)& done
wait
```

Notes:

- `N=3` defines the number of parallel executions.
- `for (( i = 0; i < N; i++ )); do ... done` for loop like in other languages
- You can write `(( i = 1; i <= N; i++ ))` instead of `(( i = 0; i < N; i++ ))` to get values 1..3 instead 0..2 for variable `i`.
- `( ... )` declares a sub-shell.
- The `&` behind `)` starts the sub-shell in the background
- `wait` waits until all sub-shells are terminated.